# How to find most frequent words in CSV file column ignoring extra comma?

Tags: java, csv

I've got a CSV file diary.csv like this:

```
WeekDay, Comments
monday, repairing a car
tuesday, car repair is done
wednesday, watched movie "Dude, where's my car?"
```

I need to find the most frequent words in Comments column ignoring extra comma. I surfed for the answer but couldn't find all in one solution in java. Can it be done as less verbosely as possible in pure java or i have to use such libs as OpenCSV?

Comment: `line.split(", ", 2)`?

Comment: This doesn't seem like valid CSV. If the separator (comma in this case) is used in a field value, it should either be escaped, or the entire field should be enclosed in characters (such as double or single quotes) indicating its boundaries. Neither is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. You have to provide your path to the file as the first argument. Good luck!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
throws Exception {
    Map<String, AtomicInteger> words = new HashMap<>();
    boolean isFirstLine = true;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (isFirstLine) {
                isFirstLine = false;
                continue;
            }
            Arrays.stream(line.split(",", 2)[1].split("\\s"))
                    .filter(str -> !str.isEmpty())
                    .map(str -> str.replaceAll("[\"?]", ""))
                    .forEach(word -> words.computeIfAbsent(word, key -> new AtomicInteger())
                                          .incrementAndGet());
        }
    }
    Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> winner = words.entrySet().stream()
            .reduce(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("", new AtomicInteger()),
                   (a, b) -> a.getValue().get() > b.getValue().get() ? a : b);
    System.out.printf("And the winner is [%s] with [%s] occurrences.\n",
                      winner.getKey(), winner.getValue().get());
}
```

Given your example file:

```
WeekDay, Comments
monday, repairing a car
tuesday, car repair is done
wednesday, watched movie "Dude, where's my car?"
```

**Output**

```
And the winner is [car] with [3] occurrences.
```

Comment: Pretty nice. Word counting is kinda tricky, though, since natural language is nonregular.

Comment: @G_H: the whole implementation is quick and dirty and a bit fuzzy. It ignores many winners and there are probably many more cleanup characters besides `"` and `?` but hopefully it is a starting point for the OP.

Comment: The lambda approach seems great for populating the map. For the CSV parsing I'd rather take a chance on OpenCSV or Apache Commons CSV since there's a lot to trip up on that the libraries take care of. But it depends quite a bit on what assumptions can be made of the input and what the use-case is of course.

Comment: That's a nice solution using streams. I also want to focus my question. What if i need to have in output more than one word, i.e. including "repair" which is a part of "repairing" specifying this task by minimum characters which must match and appear one after another.

Comment: @L.Alexander: you would have to create a tree-structure where the path from the root to a inner node or a leaf forms the word you found. Each inner node and leaf have to track the number of occurrences for complete words only. Then the effective count for a inner node would be the sum of its occurrence count and the effective count of all its direct children. Did you got the idea?